# offset in makeRegrTask mlr package

Tags: xgboost, mlr

Is it possible to have an offset in mlr makeRegrTask?

I want to use xgboost with a poisson count objective with non-unit weights and hence wish to use base_margin but unless I am missing something this is not available with package mlr for xgboost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hyperparameter in the xgboost learner, which is currently not included.

You can currently only change "base_score" as you can see here:
https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/RLearner_regr_xgboost.R

You can use the functions there and add the parameter "base_margin" into the learner, then you can also use it in mlr. (A description of how to build a learner can be found here: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html)